# Spring REST API: Return Default Preferences

Tags: java, spring, rest, java-8, spring-rest

I have developed a Spring REST API that retrieves the calling preferences of a customer from the database (Postgres).

I have a class for CallPreferences as below.

```
public class CallPreferences {
   private Boolean allowInternationalCalling;

   private Boolean allowInternationalRoaming;

   private List<DataOptions> dataOptions;

   private AutoPayPrefences autoPayPreferences;

   // getter and setters.

}
```

All the above preferences are saved in a single column in a table. A row in the table may look like below

```
Customer_Id | customer_preferneces
10112       | "preferences":  {"allowInternationalCalling": false,
                           "allowInternationalRoaming": true,
                           "dataOptions": ["plan" : "4GLTE",
                                        "data-limit" : "10GB" ],
                           "autoPay": {"payment-option" : "creditcard",
                                       "payment-date": "2nd every month", 
                                        "reminder": "email"}
                             }
```

I use row mapper to map the preferences in the database to the POJO

When there is no preferences found in the database, I would want to respond with default preferences as below.

```
"preferences":    {
  "allowInternationalCalling": true,
  "allowInternationalRoaming": true,
  "dataOptions": [],
  "autoPay": {}
}
```

I know that we can just initialize the values in the class level or if the preferences == null, i can set the default values for each properties. But wondering if there is any better way doing this using spring features.

Comment: How about overloading constructors ?

Answer (score 0):

When generating classes with Jaxb, every List attributes has the getter that assert the attribute is initialised if null. I think this is the philosophy of marshalling/unmarshalling objects with non nullable attributes.